# Syntax Error in Complex Query

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

```
UPDATE emr_cwagreich.patient_medication a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emr_cwagreich.patient_medication_archive.id AS id,
        emr_cwagreich.patient_medication_archive.drug_syn_id AS drug_syn_id, 
        pk.NDC10 AS ndc10, 
        pk.NDC11 AS ndc11, 
        pk.PackageID AS package_id, 
        pd.ProductID AS product_id, 
        pd.MarketedProductID AS marketed_product_id,
        pgns.GenericNameLong AS medication_name
    FROM emr_cwagreich.patient_medication_archive
    JOIN ep_api.CORE_GENDRUG_SYNONYM cgs ON emr_cwagreich.patient_medication_archive.drug_syn_id = cgs.DRUG_SYN_ID
    JOIN ep_api.NDC_PKG_PRODUCT npp ON cgs.DRUG_SYN_ID = npp.DRUG_SYN_ID
    JOIN ep_alchemy.package pk ON npp.CORE_10 = pk.NDC10
    JOIN ep_alchemy.product pd ON pk.ProductID = pd.ProductID
    JOIN ep_alchemy.product_generic_name_stub pgns ON pd.ProductID = pgns.ProductID
    GROUP BY medication_name
    ORDER BY COUNT(pgns.GenericNameLong) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.ndc10 = b.ndc10,
    a.ndc11 = b.ndc11,
    a.package_id = b.package_id,
    a.product_id = b.product_id,
    a.marketed_product_id = b.marketed_product_id,
    a.medication_name = b.medication_name
WHERE (b.drug_syn_id <> "" AND b.drug_syn_id IS NOT NULL)
AND
(a.product_id = "" OR a.product_id IS NULL)
AND 
a.id = 17221
```

The query above has a syntax error. My DB admin tool (HeidiSQL) told me that there was a syntax error near line 2, but I can't for the life of me figure out where it is...

Huge props to anyone who gets this.

To Fabio: The error is (word for word)

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'UPDATE emr_cwagreich.patient_medication a INNER JOIN (SELECT emr_cwagrei' at line 2
```

I've reduced it down to the subselect that's in the inner join statement (and for that matter, I've reduced the complexity of this subselect by removing a join). 
Here it is:

```
SELECT pma.id AS id,
    pma.drug_syn_id AS drug_syn_id, 
    pk.NDC10 AS ndc10, 
    pk.NDC11 AS ndc11, 
    pk.PackageID AS package_id, 
    pk.ProductID AS product_id,
    pgns.GenericNameLong AS medication_name
FROM emr_cwagreich.patient_medication_archive pma
JOIN ep_api.CORE_GENDRUG_SYNONYM cgs ON pma.drug_syn_id = cgs.DRUG_SYN_ID
JOIN ep_api.NDC_PKG_PRODUCT npp ON cgs.DRUG_SYN_ID = npp.DRUG_SYN_ID
JOIN ep_alchemy.package pk ON npp.CORE_10 = pk.NDC10
JOIN ep_alchemy.product_generic_name_stub pgns ON pk.ProductID = pgns.ProductID
GROUP BY medication_name
ORDER BY COUNT(pgns.GenericNameLong) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query is NOT returning a syntax error. It is just taking really long (even though I've placed indexes on the foreign keys...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL statement is not laid out quite correctly.

You can't alias table `emr_cwagreich.patient_medication` as `a` after the `UPDATE` statement, it needs to come later, after the `SET` statement.  Try rearranging your query like this:

```
UPDATE  a
  SET   a.ndc10 = b.ndc10,
        a.ndc11 = b.ndc11,
        a.package_id = b.package_id,
        a.product_id = b.product_id,
        a.marketed_product_id = b.marketed_product_id,
        a.medication_name = b.medication_name
  FROM  emr_cwagreich.patient_medication a
    INNER JOIN
...
```

Note the addition of the `FROM` statement after the `SET`s, at which point you can then alias your update table and join to other tables.

Comment: I have a similar query with the same structure > "UPDATE table_name t INNER JOIN..." working without any problem, it doesn't need to be after the SET.

Comment: @Chococroc I've modified the answer to hopefully clarify further, however the OP's query produces the same error in my SQL editor and works if laid out as per my answer.

Comment: It's weird, I mean, IMO no rewriting would have to be necessary, but if the query works after the rewriting you suggest, I have nothing to say but something new to learn, XD

Answer (score 0):

To properly debug:

Throw only the SELECT inside the Update, and check the SELECT is giving you back the proper result, probably your error is there. I don't see errors at the beginning of the query, the `UPDATE emr_cwagreich.patient_medication a INNER JOIN ( ...` seems to be right.

It is the field in the SELECT right? I've never seen anything as   `emr_cwagreich.patient_medication_archive.id` why you have three specification items?

### UPDATE

Try your UPDATE with the new select, and check if works:

```
UPDATE emr_cwagreich.patient_medication a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT pma.id AS id,
    pma.drug_syn_id AS drug_syn_id, 
    pk.NDC10 AS ndc10, 
    pk.NDC11 AS ndc11, 
    pk.PackageID AS package_id, 
    pk.ProductID AS product_id,
    pgns.GenericNameLong AS medication_name
    FROM emr_cwagreich.patient_medication_archive pma
    JOIN ep_api.CORE_GENDRUG_SYNONYM cgs ON pma.drug_syn_id = cgs.DRUG_SYN_ID
    JOIN ep_api.NDC_PKG_PRODUCT npp ON cgs.DRUG_SYN_ID = npp.DRUG_SYN_ID
    JOIN ep_alchemy.package pk ON npp.CORE_10 = pk.NDC10
    JOIN ep_alchemy.product_generic_name_stub pgns ON pk.ProductID = pgns.ProductID
    GROUP BY medication_name
    ORDER BY COUNT(pgns.GenericNameLong) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.ndc10 = b.ndc10,
    a.ndc11 = b.ndc11,
    a.package_id = b.package_id,
    a.product_id = b.product_id,
    a.marketed_product_id = b.marketed_product_id,
    a.medication_name = b.medication_name
WHERE (b.drug_syn_id <> "" AND b.drug_syn_id IS NOT NULL)
AND
(a.product_id = "" OR a.product_id IS NULL)
AND 
a.id = 17221
```